# php strtotime function

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I using PHP's strtotime function for converting date from one format to another 
i have the following

```
$date = "12-22-2011";

 echo $newDateFormat = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date) );

// Output 1970-01-01
// But when i replace "-"  with "/" I get proper output
$date = "12/22/2011";

echo $newDateFormat = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date) );

// Output 2011-12-22
```

Why so ? 
or is there any other function which accepts anything and convert to proper date format ?

Comment: I tried your example at http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and got `2019-04-03` for the first echo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) documentation:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

Essentially, hyphenated dates are assumed to be d-m-y, and never m-d-y.

For customised parsing, use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`.

Answer (score 2):

Using a format such as `dd-mm-yyyy` or `mm-dd-yyyy` is not quite safe : `strtotime()` cannot know for sure which one of those you used *(think about `06-11-2011`, for example : is it in june, or in november ?)*.

With `strtotime()`, you are generally better off using `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

If you want to parse a date in a specific, known, format, you should use [**`DateTime::createFromFormat()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) -- note it's only available for PHP >= 5.3.